# How to debug this nodejs code?

Tags: javascript, debugging, node.js

I'm trying to learn the "q" library with node.

```
$ node -v // -> v0.6.6
```

I'm using the latest `q.js` from https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/master/q.js now. I copied the code into a `q.js` file which is the sibling of my `testq.js` file.

The code of `testq.js` is:

```
function step1(callback) { console.log("step1"); callback("abc"); };

var Q = require("./q");

Q.fcall(step1).end();
```

When I run it:

```
node testq.js
```

It reports:

```
E:\WORKSPACE_NODE\TestNodeJs\q>node testq.js
step1

node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
          ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at step1 (E:\WORKSPACE_NODE\TestNodeJs\q\testq.js:1:112)
    at makePromise.<anonymous> (E:\WORKSPACE_NODE\TestNodeJs\q\q.js:541:27)
    at makePromise.promiseSend (E:\WORKSPACE_NODE\TestNodeJs\q\q.js:325:41)
    at Array.0 (E:\WORKSPACE_NODE\TestNodeJs\q\q.js:787:28)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
```

I installed [v8 debugger plugin for eclipse](http://chromedevtools.googlecode.com/svn/update/dev/), debug it line by line. Unfortunately, I can't find the error start.

I'm a newbie to nodejs, please help me with debugging. E.g. what tool should I use? Or any other helpful method I should try?

---

**UPDATE**

Per Hogan's answer, the code:

```
function step1(callback) { console.log("step1"); };

var Q = require("./q");

Q.fcall(step1).end();
```

can be run successfully without any error.

But when I try:

```
function step1(callback) { console.log("step1"); };

var Q = require("./q");

Q.fcall(step1)
.then(function(v) {
    console.log("finished: " +v);
}, function(err){
    console.log(err);
})
.end();
```

It prints:

```
E:\WORKSPACE_NODE\TestNodeJs\q>node testq.js
step1
finished: undefined
```

I still want a demo that `step1` will pass something to the `function(v) {console.log("finished: " +v);}`, where `v` is not an `undefined`.

Comment: your not passing anything to `step1` - so `callback` is undefined

Comment: For debugging in general, check out [node-inspector](https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector)

Comment: Use the newest version https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/master/q.js

Comment: I will use the latest version of q

Comment: @Freewind - also see my edit for your version of q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your step1 look like this(modified as the last version):

```
 function step1() { console.log("step1"); return "abc" };
```

Then you will be happy.

---

Looking at the Q documentation I believe you want 'Q.node(...) or Q.ncall(...) or Q.fcall(...)

I'd read about Q some more, or if you describe what you want to do I might be able to help.

---

step1 takes a parameter -- a function.

But you don't define that when you call it so `callback("abc");` is undefined.

Maybe it is clearer when you get rid of all the stuff that does not matter:

```
 function step1(callback) { console.log("step1"); callback("abc"); };

 var Q = require("q");

 Q.call(step1)
```

Comment: `Q.call(step1)` is OK, but `Q.call(step1).end()` will throw that error too. Why? how to fix the `step1` function to let my original `Q.call()...` code running?

Comment: I believe the problem is having the callback param itself.  The point of Q is that you don't need callbacks as parameters.

Comment: If your version has `call` instead of `fcall` then your first comment makes sense.  The way Q works is it does not "run" the functions unless `end()` is called.  The first `Q.call(step1)` does not call the `step1` function.

Comment: I just find the correct code, and update your answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The Q documentation is not very clear on this point - what Q.call/Q.fcall/Q.ncall does is to take a *synchronous* function (i.e. one that returns a value) and turn it into a promise.

In the docs there is a situation like this :

```
function step1 () {
    var result = 10;
    console.log('step1');
    callback(result);
}

function step2 (result) {
    result += 5;
    console.log('step2');
    callback(result);
}

step1 ( function(result) {
    step2 (result, function(result) {
        result += 5;
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

and then the doc says you can transform it like this to get the same result

```
(***)
Q.fcall(step1)
  .then(step2)
  .then( function(result) {
    result += 5;
    console.log(result);
  }).end();
```

what I found confusing here is that the two 'step1' and 'step2' functions are not the same : the 'step1' and 'step2' he is using in the 'promisified' version really look like this :

```
function step1 () {
    var result = 10;
    console.log('step1');
    return result;
}

function step2 (result) {
    result += 5;
    console.log('step2');
    return result;
}
```

using these sychronized versions of step1 and step2, you'll see that (***) above now works

---

the reason all of this is interesting (for me) is that you can use the same recipe to do this

```
function step1 () {
    var result = 10;
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    console.log('step1');
    setTimeout(deferred.resolve, 2000, result);
    return deferred.promise;
}

function step2 (result) {
    result += 5;
    console.log('step2');
    return result;
}

​Q.fcall(step1)
    .then(step2)
    .then(function(result) {
        result += 5;
        console.log(result);
    }).end();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [fcall](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) instead of call. `call` is a reserved javascript function.

Comment: I don't find the `fcall` in my version of `q`, it should be an older version, and in the README of that, it uses `call`. I copied that part from README.

Comment: Can you post a link to your version  of q then... no way to help without knowing what code you are using.